ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' when running Python file within Conda environment in VSCode
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run a Python file in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) within a Conda environment. The error message states "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'". What's puzzling is that VSCode's interpreter recognizes the 'torch' module without any errors (the import torch statement is highlighted in green). However, when I try to run the code using the "Run Code" feature in VSCode, I encounter this error. Interestingly, running the Python file from the terminal (python train.py) or using the "Run Python File" option in VSCode works perfectly fine.

Here are some additional details:

The interpreter in VSCode is correctly set to ...\anaconda3\python.exe.
I installed the libraries using the following commands:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
Both pip list and conda list show that the necessary libraries are installed within the Conda environment.
When I run where python, I get the following paths:

C:\Users\giova\anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe


Running where python3 returns C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe. I'm unsure whether I should also have 'python3' within the Anaconda environment, but I don't think so, because as I mentioned running from terminal python train.py perfectly works. Only clicking "Run Code" (play button) in VSCode gives No module named 'torch'

Could uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode be a solution?
I'm seeking insights into why this discrepancy occurs and potential solutions to resolve it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

use print( os.executable ) to see which Python is used to run code - it should gives /full/path/to/python.exe. And later in console/terminal/cmd/PoweShell use it to install module - /full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install ...

shortly: you have two Pythons. VSCode runs code with one Python but pip install modules for other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. Every Python needs own pip to install modules in own folder (and it may need to use /full/path/to/pip). But sometimes it is simpler to python -m pip instead of pip to make sure you install it for correct Python.

Okay, I tried to figure out which Python my code was using by using print(sys.version). When I run it from the command line, it correctly recognizes the Anaconda Python. However, if I click "Run Code" from VSCode, it returns the default Python on my machine, the general one, whose pip does not have the PyTorch libraries (and that's correct). The issue remains that VSCode shouldn't be running the general Python when I've set the interpreter to Anaconda's. And I don't understand why.

beter use os.executable to get /full/path/to/python.exe and later you can use this path to install module /full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install .... And if you want to use Anaconda in VSCode then you have to change it in VSCode settings - probably somewhere in File > Settings. And this is not issue - VSCode is tool to write code and it allows to use different Python in different project - Python3.8 Python3.9, Python2.7, PyPy, etc

BTW: this problem you can see in many questions on Stackoverflow for VSCode or PyCharm because both have function to set different Pythons for different projects

You need to distinguish between Run Code and Run Python File.

One of them is a Code Runner (Run Code) extension and the other is the official extension Python (Run Python File).
Code Runner is not affected by Python: Select Interpreter, it simply executes scripts using the command python -u name.py. So it doesn't necessarily use the python environment you chose for vscode.
